# assign to user to todo task in vtiger work flow

Tags: vtiger

I'm trying to add the ability to assign todo tasks to a specifc user when creating workflow. I cant seem to figure out how values are passed to the drop down list. I want to use the existing framework and not do it a roundabout hacked way. Can anyone help with this?

It seems dropdown list values somehow end up in this picklist object, but not sure where they are set.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to accomplish? When creating a new workflow and after selecting a module, you can set conditions. To assign it to a specific user, you can choose the condition

`Created By : (Users) User Name` is xyz

Is this what you are asking? Or are you asking how to create a new task?

Comment: I want to assign a specific user to a task created by a workflow. I don't see a created by: option. I did go ahead and modify the code and added a user drop down.

Answer (score 0):

1) open "includes/utils/EditViewUtils.php"

2) Search for the block starting with the line below:  (in Version 5.4.0 it is line #331):

```
if($fieldname == 'assigned_user_id' && $is_admin==false && $profileGlobalPermission[2] == 1 && ($defaultOrgSharingPermission[getTabid($module_name)] == 3 or $defaultOrgSharingPermission[getTabid($module_name)] == 0))
```

the first part of the condition should be:

```
 
$users_combo = get_select_options_array(get_user_array(FALSE, "Active", $assigned_user_id,'private'), $assigned_user_id);
```

3) Change 'private' to 'not private' (or anything else) so that line now shows:

```
 
$users_combo = get_select_options_array(get_user_array(FALSE, "Active", $assigned_user_id,'not private'), $assigned_user_id);
```

Now you can assing ToDo tasks to anyone.